# Can renegade and rogue be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I've looked up the definitions for both words and they seem different, yet similar -- especially renegade defined as 'a person behaving in a rebelliously unconventional manner' and rogue defined as 'a person that behaves in an aberrant way.'

Comment: I’ve searched Google for both definitions you’ve enclosed in quotation marks, and I can’t find either definition. Where did you get these definitions?

Comment: @user1284969632635 The former apparently from an Oxford publication. *Oxford Dictionary of Difficult Words*, *Oxford Dictionary of English*, and *Pocket Oxford American Dictionary and Thesaurus* all have it.

Answer (score 1):

According to Merriam Webster, [renegade](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renegade) is:

> 1 : a deserter from one faith, cause, or allegiance to another
>   2 : an individual who rejects lawful or conventional behavior

While [rogue](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rogue) is

> 1 : vagrant, tramp
>   2 : a dishonest or worthless person : scoundrel
>   3 : a mischievous person : scamp
>   4 : a horse inclined to shirk or misbehave
>   5 : an individual exhibiting a chance and usually inferior biological variation

So they cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: Yes, 'renegade' is usually someone who is 'on the run' or does not belong to a group. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/renegade. Rogue is just a 'baddy'.